# SAGE embargo policies for accepted manuscripts

Tags: publications

So I published an article in a journal published by SAGE in April, 2023 (this year). The article was published in the restricted access condition. I know that Taylor and Francis has an embargo period only after which the researchers can post their accepted manuscript on to repositories like reseachgate.

Do anyone know the current embargo policy for accepted manuscripts that have been published in SAGE journals? Any links would be helpful too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may depend on what type of journal. I found info on [Green Open Access](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/journal-author-archiving-policies-and-re-use) and [Gold Open Access and Sage Choice](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/reusing-open-access-and-sage-choice-content).

Comment: Have you asked the journal this information? They probably want their authors to know what the conditions are.

Answer (score 1):

Sage publishes their "reuse" policy on their website, but it is country-dependent. mkennedy's comment should be the answer, as you can find it from there link very quickly:

https://in.sagepub.com/en-in/sas/journal-author-archiving-policies-and-re-use